# How to enable the H5P_SET_CREATE_INTERMEDIATE_GROUP property in C++ API of HDF5 library?

Tags: c++, hdf5, hdf

When working with C API of HDF5 library, it is possible to create a property list for the **intermediate group creation** property like below and use it in other functions:

```
// enabling group creation with full qualified names
hid_t prop_list = H5Pcreate(H5P_LINK_CREATE);
H5Pset_create_intermediate_group(prop_list , 1);

// ....
H5Dcreate(file, datasetName, dataType, dataSpace, prop_list);
```

I am trying to do the same with C++ API like this:

```
DSetCreatPropList prop_list;
prop_list.setProperty("", ""); // what to do here?

// ...
file.createDataSet(datasetName, dataType, dataSpace, prop_list);
```

How I should initialize `prop_list` here in C++ API?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to a specific C++ library take a look at [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com) as it allows you to create a certain dataset and eventually a group (and nested groups) on-the-fly. Example:

```
HDFql::execute("create dataset my_group/my_subgroup/my_dataset as int");
```

Comment: No, I cannot user HDFql. I only can use the C++ API of HDF5.